# How to return a histogram and a scatterplot using matplot lib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I need to return both a histogram and a scatterplot in one function using matplotlib, but when I try to create the histogram after creating the scatterplot, it appears that the scatterplot gets overridden. Just wondering if anyone has any advice on this issue? Is there a way to return two plots at once if they share an x-axis?

For instance, there is paragraph included in this link  http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html about how to have 2 subplots. But I'm not sure how to do that with plt.hist() and plt.plot().

Comment: Unless I am completely misunderstanding, look under [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html)?

Comment: there's also the keyword arg [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html). If you use this it doesn't matter what order you actually call these. Just set `zorder` higher for the scatterplot than for the histogram.

Comment: what do you mean by 'return' in this context?

Comment: when I call the function, both the hist and the scatter plot should appear

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since the histogram fills the bars it is probably better to do it first then the scatter plot.